# How to popup a small window in bottom right corner at specified time in Java

Tags: java, swing, window

I set reminders in my application. I want to popup small window in bottom right corner of the screen at specified time. How can we popup a small window at any specified time which is set in reminder?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show a system tray noticfication (on Windows). If so, your app probably needs to be running as a service. I think regular apps can only show information within the application window.

Comment: Thanks.But can we set it to popup even within the application window at whatever the time is set in reminder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create Windows in Swing you can call `setLocation()` and `setSize()` to specify a specific place on the screen for a small Window.

Comment: Yes, but not getting how to set a JFrame form to popup at any particular time.

Comment: @bsm, use a Timer to wait for a specific time to execute the code you want.  This codes for a GUI or something else.  Also if you are doing a small window, I think you would want a JDialog or Window instead of JFrame.

Comment: That example is really useful. Thanks a lot @trashgod and @jzd .